# unable fetch date from youtube scrape selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, date, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is the screenshot of text i want to fetch:

[image]

full link to inspect element : -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwyVTQaBndU

I want to fetch the Jun 21, 2021 from the tag please attached screenshot.

Here is the code I tried:

```
try:
    postdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']//div[@id='info']//div[@id='date']").get_attribute(
        'innerText')
    print(postdate)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

output:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='container']//div[@id='info']//div[@id='date']"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)
```

it was working till date but i guess youtube has done some changes in format. So it is not working.

Comment: have you tried the full X-path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reliable css selector would be :

```
span#dot+yt-formatted-string
```

and there's a typo I think, it should be `innerHTML`

use it like this :

```
try:
    postdate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span#dot+yt-formatted-string").get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(postdate)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: i have one question like the code i have put it was working till yesterday cause i run it everyday suddenly youtube has done some changes in format. So it is not working. How can i overcome with it  or  anyhow i have to make  the changes manually evertime ?

Comment: see this locator :-  `span#dot+yt-formatted-string` - I have written this locator based on dot which can be seen between views and date, so in future they they remove the dot then it would fail. But chances are less. But still possible

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the following ways

X-path (which currently you are using)

```
postdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="info-strings"]/yt-formatted-string').text
print(postdate)
```

Full X-Path

```
postdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info-renderer/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/yt-formatted-string').text
print(postdate)
```

CSS-Selector

```
postdate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#info-strings > yt-formatted-string').text
print(postdate)
```

there is also another way

```
postdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[local-name()="yt-formatted-string" and @class="style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div')
print(postdate)
```

try these ways it should work!

Comment: actually i have tried all before putting question but none of them worked !! getting error like object is not iterable something.